# ASP.NET Core Attribute routing

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-routing

I am migrating a project to asp net core, but I could not configure these routes, i am using attributes to map actions.

*Code for ASP.Net WebAPI2*

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class SalesController : Controller
{
    // api/sales/1 -> ok
    [HttpGet]
    public HttpResponseMessage Get(int id)
    {
        // Logic
    }   

    // api/sales -> ok
    [HttpGet]
    public HttpResponseMessage Get([FromUri] PaginationHelper pagination)
    {
        // Logic
    }  

    // api/sales?me -> ok
    [ActionName("Get")]
    public HttpResponseMessage GetMe(bool? me)
    {
        // Logic
    }  
}
```

*Code for ASP.Net Core*

In the file *Startup.cs* is set *app.UseMvc();*

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class SalesController : Controller
{
    // api/sales/1 -> ok
    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    public IActionResult Get(int id)
    {
        // Logic
    }   

    // api/sales -> don't work
    [HttpGet] // -> ???
    public IActionResult Get(PaginationHelper pagination)
    {
        // Logic
    }  

    // api/sales?me -> don't work
    [HttpGet] // -> ???
    public IActionResult GetMe(bool? me)
    {
        // Logic
    }  
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure.. but I think that you can either add a route for that one, probably needs to precede the existing ones, or you can add a route attribute to that method with the specific route.
Route rules matter when declared, if some other catches first you won't get there..

Comment: Does this works for you?                // GET api/values
        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Get()
        {
            return Ok(new string[] { "value1", "value3" });
        }

Answer (score 8):

Maybe I'm too late to this discussion, but this could be valuable to other people who end up reading this page, like I did. The problem with your API endpoints is that you configured 2 of them to handle the same route: `GET /api/sales`.

If you try to access that route, the framework won't be able to distinguish between `Get(PaginationHelper)` and `GetMe(bool?)`. The reason why is that they both have `[HttpGet]` attribute, which means that both are capable of handling the route you specified in the `[Route("api/[controller]")]` attribute, just above your class declaration. Since those are declared as capable of handling that same route, hence your Exception (`Multiple actions matched`).

The solution for your problem depends on which action you want to handle that ambiguous route. Assuming that you want the route `GET /api/sales` to be handled by `Get(PaginationHelper)`, you can change the `GetMe(bool?)` action method and its `[HttpGet]` attribute to something like this:

```
[HttpGet("me")] // GET api/sales/me
public IActionResult GetMe() {
    // Logic
}
```

Comment: Perfect, that was exactly the solution I was looking for. Absolutely "valuable to other people who end up reading this page" !

Answer (score 6):

The new framework expects a more explicit indication of the intent of the endpoint.

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class SalesController : Controller {

    [HttpGet("{id:int}")] // GET api/sales/1
    public IActionResult Get(int id) {
        // Logic
    }

    [HttpGet] // GET api/sales?page=1 assuming PaginationHelper has page property
    public IActionResult Get([FromQuery]PaginationHelper pagination) {
        // Logic
    } 

    [HttpGet] // GET api/sales?me=true
    public IActionResult GetMe(bool? me = false) {
        // Logic
    }  
}
```

Reference [Asp.Net Core: Model Binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding)

Comment: The parameter [me] would be a filter, by default it is false but could I enter sales?me=true, in this case this attribute would not solve this problem

Comment: Don't work,

Error message:
An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.

AmbiguousActionException: Multiple actions matched. The following actions matched route data and had all constraints satisfied:

Conflict with the method
public IActionResult Get ([FromQuery] PaginationHelper page)
and
public IActionResult GetMe (bool me)